# Xamarin Android Fit Tabs

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I created my tabs in Xamarin for Android like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc102.png)

The Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      android:id="@+id/aprTabLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/TabLayout" >
      <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Itens de Seguranca" />
      <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Medidas Preventivas" />
      <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Riscos" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/aprViewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to do like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEkEg.png)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add next line in you TabLayout's style

```
  <item name="tabMaxWidth">0dp</item>
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank's!!